# Numeric Range Regular Expression to 1 decimal place

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write regular expressions for the following numeric ranges however need some assistance to write them correctly.

All numeric values to match against are to 1 decimal place.

- 0.0 To 59.9
- 60.0 to 119.9
- 120.0 to 239.9
- 240.0 to 419.9
- 1200.0 to 1799.9
- Anything greater than 3600.0

I believe I've manage to correctly get the correct Regular expression for the 0.0 to 59.9 range however am having difficulty with the others.

```
^[1-5]?([1-9](?:\.[0-9])?|0?\.[1-9])$
```

Comment: Something like this? `(0|[^0][1-9][0-9]+)\.[0-9]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this:

```
 // 0.0 to 59.9
^[012345]?[0-9]\.[0-9]$

//60.0 to 119.9
^(?:[6789]|10|11)[0-9]\.[0-9]$

//120.0 to 239.9
^(?:1[0-9]{2}|2[0123][0-9])\.[0-9]$

//240.0 to 419.9
^(?:2[456789][0-9]|3[0-9]{2}|4[01][0-9])\.[0-9]$

//1200.0 to 1799.9
^(?:1[234567])[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]$

//Anything greater than 3600.0
^(?:36[0-9]{2}|3[789][0-9]{2}|[456789][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5}[0-9]*)\.[0-9]$
```

Comment: pls check this and comment if it is not what you expected.  Also if you want all in one regex then concate each with " | "  ( OR case ).

Comment: Thanks @Vegeta. Everything looks good but the  Anything greater than 3600.0 regex. For example if 4000.1 for example it doesn't match.

Comment: oh... let me try again.

Comment: check ^(?:36[0-9]{2}|[456789][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5}[0-9]*)\.[0-9]$

Comment: The one above wasn't validated for 3700.0 - 3999.9. Changed your regex to ^(?:(3[6789])[0-9]{2}|[456789][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5}[0-9]*)\.[0-9]$  which seems to work

Comment: ^(?:36[0-9]{2}|3[789][0-9]{2}|[456789][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5}[0-9]*)\.[0-9]$

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong tool for the job. While you could use a regex to do what you're trying to do, it's not well suited to do it well let alone efficiently.  A simple `if`, `else if`, and `else` construct will suit you the best.  If you want to ignore anything after the first decimal place when doing the check, you can use `.toFixed(1)` and then convert it back to a float using `parseFloat(string)`.  You could also use `Math.round(float)` depending on how you want to treat numbers with more than one decimal place.

Note: The specific functions given are JavaScript examples, depending on your language they may be slightly different.

Comment: I only have the option to use Regular expressions unfortunately. It's for use in a Adobe Analytics auto classification.